# Proper way to pass on "this" to custom Tap event callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, this, tap

I picked up a some code for a JavaScript tap event for touch devices here : [GitHub page](https://github.com/jornki/Demos/blob/master/libs/touchevents/toucheventsJQ.js). *Credit to [Jørn Kinderås](http://kinderas.blogspot.ca/2012/02/javascript-tap-event-for-touch-devices.html) for this code.*

My problem is that if I do something like this :
    $('.support input').tap(function () {
        $(this).click();
    });

It doesn't work because `this` is referring to `DOMWindow` (as I can see by doing a `console.log(this)`.

The workaround I have found for now is to change a couple lines in the tap event code. I changed the following :

```
elem.on('touchend', _bind(function (e) {
    endTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (!didMove && ((endTime - startTime) < tapCancelTime)) {
        callback(e);
    }
}, this));
```

To this:

```
elem.on('touchend', _bind(function (e) {
    endTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (!didMove && ((endTime - startTime) < tapCancelTime)) {
        elem.onTap = callback;
        elem.onTap(e);
    }
}, this));
```

I feel there is probably a better way to do this the the whole `elem.onTap = callback;` feels dirty.

Here is the source code from GitHub :

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict"
    $.fn.tap = function (callback) {
        var version, didMove, tapCancelTime, startTime, endTime, _bind;
        version = "1.0.1";
        tapCancelTime = 2 * 1000;
        _bind = function (fn, me) { return function () { return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };

        return this.each(
            function (index, element) {
                var elem = $(element);

                elem.on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                elem.on('touchstart', _bind(function (e) {
                    didMove = false;
                    startTime = new Date().getTime();
                }, this));
                elem.on('touchmove', _bind(function (e) {
                    didMove = true;
                }, this));
                elem.on('touchend', _bind(function (e) {
                    endTime = new Date().getTime();
                    if (!didMove && ((endTime - startTime) < tapCancelTime)) {
            callback(e);
                    }
                }, this));
                elem.on('touchcancel', _bind(function (e) {
                    callback(e);
                }, this));
            }
        );
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.apply()` or `.call()` to pass on a desired value of `this` to any function.

In your case, you can change this:

```
callback(e);
```

to this:

```
callback.call(this, e);
```

or this (either will probably work in your case):

```
callback.call(elem, e);
```

and then the callback function will have the value of `this` from your event handler instead of `window`.  FYI, you use `.call()` when you know all the arguments you want to pass to your method/function.    You use `.apply()` when you have an array-like data structure of arguments and you want to pass all the arguments in the array.

For reference, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for more info on `.call()` and `.apply()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

```
var $this = this;
$('.support input').tap(function () { $this.click(); });
```

or

```
$('.support input').tap(function(o){return function () { o.click(); };}(this));
```